# Image will not center in parent div

Tags: html, css

I have been messing with this for some time and I cannot seem to get it right. I have a parent div that has a width and height set to 100%. Everything I have looked for in searches say to call the class and then image, like this:

`.hand img`

Then set the display to block and margin to auto.

This is not working for me. I have the top set to 50%, so that aspect of it is fine, it is just horizontally the image will not center.

The snippet I created is not replicating my issue, so please go here to see it. The hand is what I need centered.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[enter link description here](http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index)

```css
.blue {
 /*background-color: #ba5a45;*/
 background-color: #0085A1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
}
.hand {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
    animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
}
.hand img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
<img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/hand.png" class="hand">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your hand class

```
.hand {
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
}
```

It's work. I added picture as a proof

[image]

Comment: But it doesn't though. It puts the hand in the correct position at first, but then when my animation starts, my hand gets all out of wack and moves everywhere instead of staying in the static position that it should.

Comment: Your objective is to make the hand center so i already did answer your question. For the next question please post another at Stackoverflow. Just tag me the post and i will try to see what is wrong with your animation. Welcome.  =)

Answer (score 0):

When you take ".hand img", it will check the img tag inside the .hand div.It's not correct in your case.

You can take,

```
img.hand {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

As your img tag's class is hand.This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look. you did wrong

```css
.blue {
 /*background-color: #ba5a45;*/
 background-color: #0085A1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
.hand {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
    animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
<img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/hand.png" class="hand">
</div>
```

Comment: This make the keyframe rotate get all out of wack

Comment: I have date code. Please have a look. You can make text-align: center on parent and remove display:block from img

Comment: Still didn't help. The image is sitting away from the left initially and I am not sure why.

Comment: you did wrong here extra styles http://prntscr.com/9vd4wz
Now its updated please have a look once

Comment: did you understand or not?

Comment: This centered it, but it now is at the top of the page.

Comment: you can change position top 50% of .hand selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `.hand img` to either `.blue img` or  `.blue > img`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear if this is what you want, but setting max-height and max-width both to 100% moves the image to the center.

```css
.blue {
 /*background-color: #ba5a45;*/
 background-color: #0085A1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
}
.hand {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
    animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
<img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/hand.png" class="hand">
</div>
```

Comment: I need the blue div set to 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

Give `position: relative;` to `.blue` and `left:50%` to `.hand` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` will work for you.

```css
.blue {
 /*background-color: #ba5a45;*/
 background-color: #0085A1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
.hand {
    -webkit-animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
     animation: 4s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running wave;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: auto;
}
.hand img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
<img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/hand.png" class="hand">
</div>
```